# How can i add a particular branch To SourceTree

Tags: sourcetree

I want to add specific git project branch to an existing git project. How can i add a particular branch of a repository as a module in sourcetree instead of default master branch

I have a repository **x** in git.Now in that repository **x** there are sub branches like x-bugfix, x-release , develop / master branch. Now i want to add x-release as a submodule for my project Y . If i try it with Sourcetree it is adding only develop/master branch. How can i specify to sourcetree like x-release branch need to add as a submodule.

Comment: Did you try merging? Sorry I am unable to understand your question, can you please explain it further?

Comment: I updated my question with explanation. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree 1.9.6.1 in which i verified , When click on Add module it will show popup and ask repository and local path. There is Advanced options button which will ask source Branch. In that source branch we can give what ever branch we want to make submodule.